# Correct symbol for the Laplace operator ($\Delta$)

Tags: symbols

What is the correct symbol to use for the Laplace operator? It looks almost like the big Delta `$\Delta$`, but it should look different so that it is not confused with the Delta.

Currently, I use `$\vec \nabla^2$`, which is unambiguous, but not pretty.

Comment: According to the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List `\Delta` is used for it. See page 50.

Comment: Also, the only symbol used on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) - the source of all knowledge - is `\Delta` (apart from `\mathcal{L}`). :)

Comment: Link to [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/). See page 50.

Comment: don't you mean page 150, @azetina? Page 50 has only arrows.

Comment: @JorgeCampos It may depend on which version you are looking at. There is the a4 paper size or letter size compiled symbol list, I guess.

Comment: Even if they look different, they will be confused. Don't use them with different meanings! (The same applies, e.g., to `\epsilon` and `\varepsilon`.)

Comment: @azetina, I downloaded the one from your link  ...

Comment: @HendrikVogt: So what about (cylindrical polar coordinates) radius `\rho` and charge density `\rho`? Would not it improve the situation if I use `\rho` and `\varrho` consistently instead of inventing a non-standard symbol?

Comment: @queueoverflow: OK, I'm not a physicist, and I realize that I was writing from a mathematician's perspective. So I never had a situation where I had no choice but to use a rho (like for the charge density). In your case it appears that the two meaning are _very_ different, so maybe it'll be less confusing than I thought. Of course it's most confusing when both variants are used for non-standard meanings - and I know published papers where people did exactly this!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you use the D'Alembert operator as well, you might find pretty using the symbol `\bigtriangleup` for your Laplace operator, in order to get a similar look as the `\Box` symbol that is being used for D'Alambertian. In the following, a tricky construction with `\mathop` and `\mathbin` is used to get the proper spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand*\Laplace{\mathop{}\!\mathbin\bigtriangleup}
\newcommand*\DAlambert{\mathop{}\!\mathbin\Box}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
  \phi(1+\Laplace A) \neq \phi(1+\Delta A)
\\ 
  \phi(1+\DAlambert A) \neq \phi(1+\Laplace A)
\\ 
  f\Laplace g
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: I'd use `\mathop{{}\bigtriangleup}\nolimits` and `\mathop{{}\Box}\nolimits` which would ensure correct spacing in all situations. The `{}` is in order to avoid centering the operator with respect to the formula axis.

Comment: The d'Alambert operator will come eventually since I am a physicist. I like your solution, since it looks consistent.

Comment: What does  the `!\mathbin`-part actually do ? And how would you make `\bigtriangledown` look like `\nabla` (in terms of vertical spacing) ?

Comment: @hillbilly `\!`  kills the (implicit) spacing between an Op (`\mathop{...}`) and Bin (`\mathbin{...}`) atom.

Comment: @yo' and whats the Bin good for then?

Comment: @hillbilly To provide the asymetric spacing in the third example.

Comment: Just for the record: the combination “Op-Bin” is impossible (table on page 170 of the TeXbook), so the `\mathbin` does nothing at all, because `\mathbin\Box` is eventually treated as an Ord atom. The “asymmetry” in the third example is due to the fact that the atoms are “Ord-Op-(Bin->Ord)-Ord”. The space is created by the first two atoms.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, the correct spelling is _d’Alembert_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator

Answer (score 24):

The operator is defined, in the international standard ISO 80000-1, as identified with the Unicode character U+2206 INCREMENT (mistakenly called DELTA in the standard), which has “Laplace operator” as one of its alias names. Thus, it is regarded as distinct from the Greek capital letter delta U+0394. This is however a logical, character-level distinction and does not imply that different glyphs must be used. On the other hand, many fonts make a distinction, sometimes very small, sometimes quite noticeable.

It seems to me that to make the difference in LaTeX, you would need to use a package that lets you enter a character by its Unicode number or enter Unicode characters as such. Along that second option, the following code seems to produce different renderings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
U+2206: $∆$

U+0394: $Δ$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of modifying your example; first to use `XITS Math` which is the same as `STIXGeneral`, but doesn't raise warnings when used as a math font. The other change is for making clear what Unicode character produces each glyph.

Comment: @egreg: Could you please add a possibility to define a command for the "U+2206". I would like to get a "`\laplace`" working with `lualatex` and `\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}`. Thanks!

Comment: @LaRiFaRi The symbol is called `\increment` with `unicode-math`. If you want `\laplace` to use it, just do `\newcommand{\laplace}{\increment}`

Comment: It seems that unfortunately the package `unicode-math` requires one of the compilers `xelatex` or `Lualatex`.

Answer (score 18):

According to the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/) one can use the symbol `\Delta` and corresponding `\nabla` to represent the Laplace operator.

[image]

I don't know if `\Updelta` is a possibility from  `txfonts/pxfonts`.

Answer (score 4):

There is another way to display the Laplacian. I found it in accident.

`\mathcal{4}`

So you can also define

```
\newcommand*\laplace{\mathop{}\!\mathcal{4}}
```

Comment: this though depends on the (limitation of) certain font engines, and you should not rely on this . E.g. when using the package `unicode-math` (see above) `\mathcal{4}` will print `4`